# How can I close the sidebar menu? (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a side-menu on my bootstrap webpage which is open by default.
If the screen is too small there is a button placed behind it to open the menu again.

When a user clicks on a link I would like the menu to close automatically.

The button I already have opens the menu perfectly, but I have no way of closing it?

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#/"><img src="/content/img/AAA.png" width="27px" />Menu</a></li>
                <li data-ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth"><a href="#/Page2">Welcome {{authentication.userName}}</a></li>
                <li data-ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth"><a href="#/Page2">Page1</a></li>
                <li data-ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth"><a href="" data-ng-click="logOut()">Logout</a></li>
                <li data-ng-hide="authentication.isAuth"><a href="#/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</a></li>
                <li data-ng-hide="authentication.isAuth"><a href="#/signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">
        Menu
    </a>

    <script>
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add in another event handler for the a elements.

```
    $(".sidebar-nav li a").click(function() {
        $("#wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things that you could do:

- You could use hide/show with jQuery(I can see you are already using it).
- Instead of makeing a "toggled" class, Bootstrap has a built in "hidden" class that you could use.
- You could also toggle it's css "display" value.
- You could use the "animate" class to slide the menu on and off the screen.
- You could have a variable to store the state of the menu("true" for out, "false" for in), and change it when the toggle button is clicked.

I had a similar issue, and I placed a close button on the menu, and added a seperate click handler that would close the menu. The close button would then hide with the menu, leaving just the button to open the menu again.